# Site URL blocked as "Spammy", but also no data was scraped in debug

Tags: facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api, blocked

Made a website for a client of mine who owns a small business. About three months ago, her site URL was blocked by Facebook for being "Spammy". We launched a pretty impressive "Go Here And Report It As Safe" campaign, but alas, it's not unblocked.

We made a new domain that mirrored the blocked one. This worked for about an hour. Then lo and behold! It got blocked too.

I was very curious, so I decided to try out the "Object Debugger". When I did, I got this message:

"Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

I tried it again a few hours later, and it scraped just fine! Not only did it scrape and show up in debug perfectly, but it also didn't ping as blocked when I posted to my wall! It was amazing.

Sadly, I made an edit to the header file (just took away a meta tag), and now it won't scrape again. And it's blocked again.

The URL in question is enchantedcareers.com.

I feel like maybe the site isn't being blocked as spammy, but rather, there may be some kind of coding problem? Anyone else had an OG bug ping a URL as blocked upon link shim?

**EDIT :** Again, it let me post the link, with full preview and everything. I posted it, and about one minute later, the post was removed, and it was back to being "spammy" 
The URL Debugger only scrapes my URL sporadically (with no page edits being made whatsoever).

I can't find a pattern.

- no data was scraped: 9:06
- successful scrape: 9:34
- no data was scraped: 9:44
- successful scrape: 10:04
- no data was scraped: 10:08

**Edit #2 :** This is just completely crazy. Our new domain, enchantedcareers.net, which is nothing but my host's default quickstart.html page, is also blocked from being posted. When I try to post the .net domain, it gives me both the .net and .com domain as being blocked.

THE .COM DOMAIN ISN'T EVEN TIED TO THE .NET NAME. This domain is straight out of the box. Why is it bringing that domain up when I try to post a new one?

I'm just so confused.

It won't scrape the .net name, either.

Could this be a server thing...?

Answer (score 1):

Your URI comes up clean on a URIBL check, you're on Dream Host, which is typically reliable, so I wouldn't expect to see your IP address show up in an DNSBL check. I don't see any glaring errors in your page code that typically causes the Facebook parser to choke.

There is one "suspicious" script on your page according to [this report](http://www.UnmaskParasites.com/security-report/?page=enchantedcareers.com). Try removing this, clear your cache and see if Facebook will parse your URL.

Comment: OOOO, okay, so I removed that affiliate tracking script, and it now will parse on the developer debug. It still says blocked when I try to post it on my wall, but I wasn't sure which cache to clear? My browser? My server?

Comment: Also thanks sooooo much for the help. We've been pulling our hair out about this for months. You're awesome!

Comment: Basically, sometimes it will parse, and sometimes it won't. There's no rhyme or reason. Is it always so sporadic?